# Possible to auto update JRE_HOME when java is updated?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, solr

It took me a bit to figure out why my solr server wouldn't start up again. Apparently Java had been updated, but I didn't realize it (though it's completely possible I said okay to a dialogue and forgot about it). Even if I had realized it, I wouldn't have known right away that I needed to update the JRE_HOME environment variable for tomcat to start back up.

This was on a dev machine, so not a big deal other than just frustrating. But now I'm concerned about how to handle this in production. Do I just have to remember to update the environment variable if I update Java, or is there a way I can automatically keep it in sync?

Comment: What OS are you using?  How is Java installed?  Which one (OpenJDK?  Oracle?)  How was Solr installed?

Comment: @StephenC Microsoft and Oracle. Not sure how to answer the last question... all I know is on dev machine I start from the command prompt, but on the server it's installed as a service.

Comment: That is, I start the tomcat server (not java, obviously) from the command prompt on dev machine and it's a service on prod machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is No.  Java updates don't and can't<sup>1</sup> update JAVA_HOME automatically.

Note that this kind of problem also affects other Java-based services running on Windows.  Google for `windows server java update breaks java_home`.

---

For the record, modern Linux systems use the "alternatives" system to deal with Java version switching gracefully.  And services like Tomcat don't depends on a single system-wide JAVA_HOME variable.  Instead a typical  service has a config file that includes the JAVA_HOME to be used for that service.

You could look into how Linux does these things for ideas on how to avoid getting burned by Java updates on Windows.  But it might be more effort than it is worth.  Other approaches would be:

- use some kind of configuration management system on your Windows production server to avoid uncontrolled updates
- be more careful about enabling / using auto-updates.

---

<sup>1 ... because there is no "right way" that is going to work for all uses of Java on a Windows box.</sup>

Comment: Ok that's what I figured but figured it was worth asking. One thing that really annoys me is that when it installs the update, it deletes the old version. Why can't it leave both and if I have products with a hard reference to the old one they shouldn't break? Of course I know Java doesn't do side-by-side very well (yes, I know it can support it but it's a hassle). Maybe Java just works much better on other operating systems, but in Windows I have been disappointed by it over and over again. That is, my disappointments are never with the products written in Java, but by Java itself.

Comment: Yes ... well ... one of the reasons that Java works better on Linux is that the Linux distro maintainers play a big part in making sure that the integration is relatively seamless.